# 1D plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot in a single line ticks according to an array (up to 1000 elements). I would rather not to use something like:

```
    plt.xticks(energies[i][j])
```

because each sample value is written up below tick. I have looked extensively at Matplotlib documentation but didn't find nothing besides hist(). If you guys know other way to visualize 1D arrays into a single line I would very much appreciate, especially if it involves colors representing density of values.

I'm using Spyder 2.2.5, Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit in OSX 10.7.4

Comment: `xticks` is for setting the tick markers on the axis, don't do that.  There is also `eventplot` which might be what you want matplotlib.org/dev/examples/pylab_examples/eventplot_demo.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit**
As @tcaswell mentions in comments, [eventplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot) is a good way to do this. Here is an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
a = [1,2,5,6,9,11,15,17,18]
plt.hlines(1,1,20)  # Draw a horizontal line
plt.eventplot(a, orientation='horizontal', colors='b')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or you can use vertical line [markers](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html)? The example below has the basic idea. You could change the color of the markers to represent density.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,5,6,9,11,15,17,18]

plt.hlines(1,1,20)  # Draw a horizontal line
plt.xlim(0,21)
plt.ylim(0.5,1.5)

y = np.ones(np.shape(a))   # Make all y values the same
plt.plot(a,y,'|',ms = 40)  # Plot a line at each location specified in a
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are re-inventing `eventplot`

Comment: I didn't know about eventplot! That is much better.

Comment: Reference? I am unable to find much in matplotlib called `eventplot`?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an event plot example.