# 1D plot python colored by class

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pca

I used PCA and did dimensionality reduction to 1D for the iris dataset using the below code.

I have checked the question
[1D plot matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546552/1d-plot-matplotlib).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target

pca = PCA(n_components = 1, whiten = False)
pca.fit(X)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)


# transform
transformed = pca.fit_transform(X)


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 2))
plt.hlines(1,-10,20)  # Draw a horizontal line
plt.xlim(-5,5)
plt.ylim(0.8,1.2)

y = np.ones(np.shape(transformed))   # Make all y values the same
plt.plot(transformed,y,'x',ms = 10)  # Plot a line at each location specified in a
#plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I want to use color by the class (['setosa' 'versicolor' 'virginica']) in the figure like the below code of the dimensionality reduction to 2D.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target


pca = PCA(n_components = 2, whiten = False)
pca.fit(X)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)

transformed = pca.fit_transform(X)


# plot using color
for label in np.unique(Y):
    if label == 0:
        c = "red"
    elif label == 1:
        c = "blue"
    elif label == 2:
        c = "green"
    else:
        pass
    plt.scatter(transformed[Y == label, 0],
                transformed[Y == label, 1],
               c=c)
plt.title('principal component')
plt.xlabel('pc1')
plt.ylabel('pc2')
plt.show()
```

This might be very simple question, but I could not realize.
I would appreciate it if you show me the appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what kind of output you want but you could simply use seaborn and pass class for the `hue` argument. Read the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

```
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time")
```

For your case `data` = iris and `hue` = `class`